# Datetime in ArcGIS Pro defaults to 12/30/1899

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql-server, datetime

I have datetime field in a CSV with the following format:

```
Time    
2007-02-01 05:00:00+00:00
```

When I use the append tool in ArcGIS Pro to load data to a table on a SQL Server Enterprise geodatabase, the datetime for all records defaults to:

```
12/30/1899
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed since I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: SQL Server has more than one date datatype. Are you using the supported one?

Comment: You had a tag for Python but have not included any code to show how that is relevant to your question so I’m removing it.

Comment: @Vince  I created the table using ArcPro.   Using the interface, there's only an option for a "date" field

Comment: So then the CSV parsing is the issue, no? I don't trust CSVs farther then I can throw a minivan, so I generally parse them in Python and use an InsertCursor, vice Append.

Comment: Without an accompanying schema.ini file setting the CSV data types of columns, the datetime values are likely going to be seen as text.  The inclusion of UTC offset information in the datetime value, i.e., `+00:00`, confuses the built-in parser that would normally convert a string value representation of datetime to an actual datetime value.  When the parser gets confused, it fails back to using a datetime epoch of 12/30/1899.

Answer (score 0):

The database is reading the values as null: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/110001-120000/tool-errors-and-warnings-110401-110425-110413.htm

There might be an issue with how Pro is interpreting your data. Try importing the csv into a table, checking the data type, and then appending it.

For anyone having this issue with trying to join a field, I was having this issue when I tried to use OBJECTID or GlobalID for the join. When I used a different field to join, the correct dates came over.